# How i get my menu in the foreground?

Tags: java, html, css

I have purchased an image-gallery and implemented it into my webpage. Now the gallery is in the foreground every time and the menu is below. I have tried to fix it with z-index but it doesn't seem to work.

I have uploaded the webpage so that you can see the code. I'm unable to post the java code because I purchased it and I'm not allowed to post it.

[Link to see what i mean](http://beta.chantale.tk/galerie.html)

Thanks for your help,

Patrick

---

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>Portfolio von </title>
        <meta name="description" content="Das ist das Portfolio von" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="photo, photos, Foto, Fotografie, Messerli, usw" />
        <meta name="author" content="xyz" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu_cornermorph.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/Chantale-favicon.png" />
        <!--NUR BEI GALLERIE!!! -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/global.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="java/FWDIGP.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="menu-wrap">
                <nav class="menu">
                    <!-- <div class="profile"><img src="img/user1.png" alt="Matthew Greenberg"/><span>Matthew Greenberg</span></div> -->
                    <div class="link-list">
                        <a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span>About me</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span>My Photos</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span>Security &amp; Privacy</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span>Personal Settings</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span>Security &amp; Privacy</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon-list">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.behance.net/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-behance"></i></a>
                        <a href="http://instagram.com/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <button class="menu-button" id="open-button"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i><span>Menu öffnen</span></button>
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="vert-galerie">
                        <div class="table">
                            <div class="vert-fix">
                                <div id="galerie">
                                    <div id="Playlist" >
                                        <ul data-category-name="Alle Bilder">
                                            <li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/1.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/1.jpg">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">Infinite Grid Pro</p>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DescP">Multimedia infinite grid for your website that can only be found on sale here, it runs on all major browsers and mobile devices like iPhone, iPad, IOS, Android and Windows8.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/2.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/2.jpg">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">Revolution Lightbox, think outside the lightbox!</p>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DescP">Full blown multimedia responsive lightbox included, it runs on all major browsers and mobile devices like iPhone, iPad, iOS, Android and Windows8. It has support for image, video (mp4), audio (mp3), Vimeo, YouTube, iFrame, Google maps and flash.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/3.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/3.jpg">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">Support for unlimited categories!</p>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DescP">Supports unlimited categories and each categories can have unlimited content.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/4.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/4.jpg">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">Customizable thumbnails action</p>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DescP"> When a thumbnail is pressed you can choose to do nothing, display multimedia content using our great <a href="http://www.webdesign-flash.ro/p/rl/" target="_blank">revolution lightbox</a>, or to open a new webpage. The lightbox has support for image, video (mp4), audio (mp3), Vimeo, YouTube, iFrame, Google maps and flash.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/5.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/5.jpg">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">Outstanding performance using OOP code and CSS3</p>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DescP">High performance using OOP code and the latest CSS3 techniques, ready for mobile with swipe and pinch support, very flexible, easy to setup and extremely customizable.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/6.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/6.jpg">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">Support for four display types</p>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DescP">Support for four display types, responsive, fixed, fullscreen and fluid width.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/7.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/7.jpg">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">Optional drop down categories menu</p>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DescP">Optional drop down categories menu, this categories selector can be positioned on the left or right side of the grid canvas.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/8.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/8.jpg">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">Customizable drag</p>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DescP">Customizable drag, the grid drag direction can be set to horizontal, vertical, both or none.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/9.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/9.jpg">
                                                <div>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">Auto scroll</p>
                                                    <p class="gallery1DescP">Auto scroll, the grid can be set to auto scroll, the auto scroll direction and speed are customizable.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /content-wrap -->
        </div><!-- /container -->
        <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**menu_cornermorph.css:**

```
html, 
body, 
.container, 
.content-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    background: #373a47;
}

.content-wrap {
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    background: #b4bad2;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.content::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0s 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

/* Menu Button */
.menu-button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.25em;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #373a47;
    background: transparent;
}

.menu-button span {
    display: none;
}

.menu-button:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

/* Menu */
.menu-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #ebedf4;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 1em;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .menu-button {
        margin: 0.25em;
    }
    .menu-wrap {
        bottom: 0.25em;
        left: 0.25em;
    }
}

.menu {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 0.65em;
    color: #64697d;
    text-align: left;
}

.profile {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 42px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 1em;
}

.profile img {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.link-list {
    padding: 1.35em 0;
    margin: 0 0.75em;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(125,129,148,0.2);
}

.link-list a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.25em 0;
    color: #7d8194;
    padding: 0.5em 1.5em 0.5em 0em;
}

.link-list a:hover,
.link-list a:focus {
    color: #64697d;
}

.link-list a span {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon-list {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    bottom: 0.9em;
}

.icon-list a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 0.25em;
    color: rgba(125,129,148,0.5);
}

/* Shown menu */
.show-menu .content::before {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.show-menu .menu-wrap {
    width: 280px;
    height: 340px;
    -webkit-animation: anim-jelly 0.8s linear forwards;
    animation: anim-jelly 0.8s linear forwards;
}

.show-menu .menu {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: This seems [familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925530/how-can-i-get-my-menu-in-the-foreground).

Comment: did you try giving the menu z-index: 1000 and the pictures z-index: 0?

Comment: Yeah but it did't worked...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch
I have edited the question, because I do not ask the good provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    background: #b4bad2;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;     //insert this line
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
But is there a way that the lightbox of the menu cover the gallery?

Comment: Yes, changing the z-index would work. I guess you have done it. Seems to be working good.